# React-Redux - Hooks API

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to configure my new react-redux application to use the new features of React-Redux. The [official documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks) says

> React Redux now offers a set of hook APIs as an alternative to the existing connect() Higher Order Component.

I have been trying to find some helping articles related to Hooks API with some real examples but all react-redux Apps are using connect function. Official documentation also shows very basic examples.

**I want to change the connect functions in my App with useSelector (offered by Hooks API).**

Here is an example code snippet from my application.

```
//MessagesListContainer
export default connect(
  // mapStateToProps
  (state:State) => ({
    activeUser: getActiveUser(state),   
    messages: getMessagesList(state),   
  })
)(MessagesList)

//Selectors
export const getActiveUser = (state: State) => state.activeUser;
export const getMessagesList = (state : State) => (
  Object.keys(state.messages).map((key : any)=> state.messages[key])
)

export interface IMessagesListProps {
  activeUser?: User;
  messages?: Message[];
}
/**
 *  Messages List
 */
export default class MessagesList extends PureComponent<IMessagesListProps> {
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hooks are not compatible with Class components.
To use Hooks, you convert the class components to function components.
For instance, your code can be refactored to

```
/**
 *  Messages List
 */

const getActiveUser = (state: State) => state.activeUser;
const getMessagesList = (state : State) => (Object.keys(state.messages).map((key : any)=> state.messages[key]));

const MessagesList: React.FC = () => {
  const activeUser = useSelector(getActiveUser);
  const messagesList = useSelector(getMessagesList);

  ....
}

export default MessagesList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hooks API facilitates function components, so I nested my class component inside a function component like this:

```
//messages-list.container.tsx
//MessagesListContainer
export const MessagesListContainer = () => {
   const activeUser= useSelector((state:State) => getActiveUser(state));
   const messages= useSelector((state:State) => getMessagesList(state));
   return <MessagesList activeUser={activeUser} messages={messages} />
}


//Selectors
export const getActiveUser = (state: State) => state.activeUser;
export const getMessagesList = (state : State) => (
  Object.keys(state.messages).map((key : any)=> state.messages[key])
)

//end of messages-list.container.tsx

//messages-list.component.tsx
export interface IMessagesListProps {
  activeUser?: User;
  messages?: Message[];
}
/**
 *  Messages List
 */
export default class MessagesList extends PureComponent<IMessagesListProps> {
.
.
.
}
```

As per my perception, it's better to keep the last level components isolated from the store.